# Ionic Capacitor's Accessibility.speak API not working on iOS, works on Android

Tags: ios, accessibility, capacitor

The Accessibility.speak function is working fine on Android, but not on iOS. I've tested on a real device iPhone 7 and in the simulator with iPhone X and iPad Pro 4th Generation.

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { Accessibility } = Plugins;

Accessibility.speak({ value: 'App is loading' });
```

I'm getting this in the console, but no audio plays...

```
Accessibility.speak(#123832822)
  Object
  callbackId: "123832822"
  methodName: "speak"
  options: {value: "App is loading"}
  pluginId: "Accessibility"
  type: "message"
```

Running the latest Capacitor

@capacitor/cli 2.2.1
@capacitor/core 2.2.1
@capacitor/ios 2.2.1
@capacitor/android 2.2.1

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can confirm this has been my experience as well (Capacitor 2.2.1)

Comment: Did anyone manage to solve this issue? Seems to be working great in the browser when serving...

Comment: @Rizz No I didn't, gave up and haven't revisited it yet .. Frustrating to hear that it's still a problem! Can't find any info about it anywhere. I opened a question on the ionic forum too, but haven't had any response. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/accessibility-speak-api-not-working-on-ios-but-works-on-android/192647